# Prn file generated by Bartender with strange characters

Tags: printing, fonts, label, character, bartender

Im trying to create prn file in order to use with another application made in Java SE; The goal and get the commands sent to the Argox OS-214Plus printer

I only add a QR code and other information in a document, then choose "print to file"

When opening prn file with notepad++, it seems with strange characters like this:

"8                                                             ÁÀ?0 ?Ýÿ ÁÀ?0 ?Íÿ ÁÀ?0 ?Ýÿ ÁÀ?0 ?Íÿ?Áó3?ÁóÁÿ?Ýÿ?Áó3?ÁóÁÿ?Íÿ?Áó3?ÁóÁÿ?Ýÿ?Áó3?ÁóÁÿ?Íÿ03<ÁüÁó?Ýÿ03<ÁüÁó?Íÿ03<ÁüÁó?ÁÁÁÿÁÏÂÿÁøÁàÁüÒÿ03<ÁüÁó?ÁÁÁÿÁÏÂÿÁøÁàÁüÂÿ03Áÿ<Áó?œÁÿÂÿÁçÁÎqÁæyÁçÒÿ03Áÿ<Áó?œÁÿÂÿÁçÁÎqÁæyÁçÂÿ03Áÿ<Áó?¾OÂÿÁÏÁîyÁç3Á÷Òÿ03Áÿ<Áó"

could you help me solve this so I can see the code for label generation?

Comment: This looks like classic character encoding mismatch. Is a PRN file a plain text file? If so, what encoding does it use, and what encoding are you telling notepad++ to use?

Comment: Hello, thank you for commenting. I can not determine if it's just text, QRCode does not seem to be plain text. The file encoding is "Windows-1252". Notepad ++ is opening with the encoding "ANSI", when I switch to UTF-8 it gets a little more readable only. I'm really confused with these encodings, saving with one and opening with another .

Comment: a casual google tells me a .prn file contains printer instructions, so I would assume that's a binary format, not something you can just read in a text editor like notepad++

Comment: So, I believe that's the case, low-level instructions. I have chosen to consult the printer manual and manually generate the code with instructions

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a normal font such as Arial for the text. The barcode is probably also controlled by BarTender. When using a normal font and letting BarTender decide the barcode it will be printed as an image and BarTender generates code like your example. Changing your font to a printerfont and changing the printmethod for the barcode should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I realized that it was happening when I set specific Symbol version.

[image]

When setting it back to Auto, issue has gone and prn file is now correctly generated. The downside is that the size of the QR code varies as the length of the content changes.